# column ambiguously defined in select case from join having oracle

Tags: database, oracle, select

getting error : `column ambiguous defined` .
I don't get why it doesn't work.
here is the code :

```
SELECT SL.id, 
       SL.sn, 
       SL.title, 
       CASE 
         WHEN SL.sn IS NOT NULL THEN PRL.start_date 
         ELSE SL.start_date 
       END AS start_date, 
       CASE 
         WHEN SL.sn IS NOT NULL THEN PRL.end_date 
         ELSE NULL 
       END AS end_date, 
       SL.father_id, 
       SL.sn, 
       SL.project, 
       SL.username, 
       SL.RUN, 
       SL.zip_path, 
       SL.log_file 
FROM   scheduler_list SL 
       left join package_running_list PRL 
              ON SL.sn = PRL.sn 
HAVING start_date >= To_date('2016-02-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
       AND ( end_date <= To_date('2016-04-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + 1 
              OR end_date IS NULL )
```

Comment: Your tables SL and PRL has start date and end date. You may need to specify which one you are using in the having clause

Comment: Why is that confusing? Your code shows you have PRL.start_date and SL.start_date, so you need to qualify the one in the `having` clause to specify which you mean. If you're attempting to refer to the alias you're creating for the case statement, you can't do that. You also don't have a group-by to go with the having clause.

Comment: OK , so how can I do i @AlexPoole ? I need an if there to decide which one to take ...

Comment: I suspect you don't mean "HAVING", you actually mean "WHERE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the `HAVING` clause to an outer select so that the use of `start_date` and `end_date` is not ambiguous between the `PRL`, `SL` tables. Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT SL.id, 
         SL.sn, 
         SL.title, 
         CASE 
           WHEN SL.sn IS NOT NULL THEN PRL.start_date 
           ELSE SL.start_date 
         END AS start_date, 
         CASE 
           WHEN SL.sn IS NOT NULL THEN PRL.end_date 
           ELSE NULL 
         END AS end_date, 
         SL.father_id, 
         SL.sn AS sn1,     -- DUPLICATE COLUMN 
         SL.project, 
         SL.username, 
         SL.RUN, 
         SL.zip_path, 
         SL.log_file 
  FROM   scheduler_list SL 
         left join package_running_list PRL 
                ON SL.sn = PRL.sn
)
WHERE  start_date >= DATE '2016-02-28' 
       AND ( end_date <= DATE '2016-04-11' OR end_date IS NULL )
```

Comment: already tried the `where` statement , but it still fails with the same error

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `SELECT` (without the `WHERE` / `HAVING` clause in another `SELECT` and then adding the `WHERE` statement to that outer `SELECT`? (As I give an example of above).

Comment: @Mojo - see my update. You are selecting `SL.sn` twice and, if this is desired, you will need to alias one of the values to have a different name.

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows you have `PRL.start_date` and `SL.start_date`, so you need to qualify the one in the `having` clause to specify which you mean - whether you want the value from `PRL` or `SL`. Without a table qualifier Oracle doesn't know which table's column you are referring to - it's ambiguous, as the error message says.

But it looks like you probably don't want either of the original table columns, and you're really attempting to refer to the column alias you're creating for the case statement. You can't do that; column aliases can't be used in the same level of a query as they are defined, except in an `order by` clause, as it says [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55280):

> **c_alias**
>   Specify an alias for the column expression. Oracle Database will use this alias in the column heading of the result set. The AS keyword is optional. The alias effectively renames the select list item for the duration of the query. The alias can be used in the *order_by_clause* but not other clauses in the query.

You will have to either repeat the `case` statements:

```
WHERE CASE 
     WHEN SL.sn IS NOT NULL THEN PRL.start_date 
     ELSE SL.start_date 
   END >= To_date('2016-02-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
   AND ( CASE 
           WHEN SL.sn IS NOT NULL THEN PRL.end_date 
           ELSE NULL 
         END <= To_date('2016-04-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + 1 
          OR CASE 
           WHEN SL.sn IS NOT NULL THEN PRL.end_date 
           ELSE NULL 
         END IS NULL )
```

(You don't have a group-by clause so `having` doesn't really make sense here, so I've changed it to `where`),

Or use a subquery/CTE/inline view:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT SL.id, 
         SL.sn, 
         SL.title, 
         CASE 
           WHEN SL.sn IS NOT NULL THEN PRL.start_date 
           ELSE SL.start_date 
         END AS start_date, 
         CASE 
           WHEN SL.sn IS NOT NULL THEN PRL.end_date 
           ELSE NULL 
         END AS end_date, 
         SL.father_id, 
         SL.project, 
         SL.username, 
         SL.RUN, 
         SL.zip_path, 
         SL.log_file 
  FROM   scheduler_list SL 
         left join package_running_list PRL 
                ON SL.sn = PRL.sn 
)
WHERE start_date >= To_date('2016-02-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
       AND ( end_date <= To_date('2016-04-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + 1 
              OR end_date IS NULL )
```

Most of your original query has moved into the inline view, which refers to your two base tables and has no ambiguity. If you run that inner query on its own you'll see it works but returns more data than you want.

I have changed the inner query to remove the duplicate references to `SL.sn`; you had that twice, which would cause the same ORA-00918 as the view would try to have two columns with the same name. If you want it twice for some reason, you'll have to list the columns in the outer select instead of using `*` and repeat it there; or keep the duplicate in the inner query but use an alias so it has a unique name. I suspect that was accidental though.

The `start_date` and `end_date` in the outer `where` clause are the result of the `case` expressions in the inner query. This avoids repeating the case logic, which is shorter, easier to read, and easier to maintain - if the logic changes you only have to change it in one place, not two or three.

The outer query cannot see the base tables or their aliases, PRL and SL, that you use in the inner query. It can only see the result set from that inner query, and there is no ambiguity in the column names in the result set.

---

Not relevant to the question, but you might want to consider using ANSI date literals, just for brevity:

```
WHERE start_date >= DATE '2016-02-28'
       AND ( end_date IS NULL OR end_date <= DATE '2016-04-10' + 1 )
```

Though that only works with fixed literals; the +1 maybe suggests your real code is being passed a string to convert to a date, in which case you would need to use `to_date()`. And that last comparison might be intended to be `<` rather than `<=`, but hard to tell.

Comment: already tried the `where` statement , but it still fails with the same error

Comment: @mojo - you'll still get the error if you used `where` at the same level of query, if you don't qualify the `start_date` to say which one you mean. You can't *just* change `having` to `where`, you need to either repeat the case statements, or use a subquery - which is easier to read and has less repetition, making maintenance easier.

Comment: Thanks for you help Alex but I'm so sorry I don't get it.
How can I qulify the start_date to be the result of the `case` statement ? and if I can't do it , what can I do ?

Comment: You don't get what? You're referring to `start_date` with no table qualifier, so Oracle doesn't know if you mean `PRL.start_date` or `SL.start_date`. If you put most of your existing query into an inline view and keep the `where` clause outside, when the `where` is evaluated there is no ambiguity - PRL and SL are out of scope, and you can only be referring to the column alias you assigned from your `case` in the inner query. Have you tried running this code?

Comment: yep , tried running it... not working... same error.

Comment: @Mojo - right, you had `SL.sn` twice in your original query. Updated. (It's the same error, but reported against a different line)

Comment: as MT02 suggested , problem was duplicated SL.sn ... thanks alot @AlexPoole !

Comment: The original code had the error in the where/having clause, the new code had it in the inline view; you still need to make the other changes, but I think you figured that out.